URL Submitter Contract Woes
I'm using SOLANG to develop a solana contract
I want to be able to send URLs to the contract data.
Do I need to use anchor or can I simply use SOLANG like below?
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract MinimalUrlSubmitter {
    uint256 constant MAX_URL_LENGTH = 256;

    struct UrlData {
        address submitter;
        bytes url;
    }

    UrlData[] public urls;

    /// Log to simulate an event
    event UrlSubmitted(address indexed submitter, bytes url);

    /// Submit a URL
    /// @param submitter The address of the user submitting the URL
    /// @param url The URL being submitted
    function submitUrl(address submitter, bytes calldata url) public {
        // Validate URL length
        require(url.length > 0 && url.length <= MAX_URL_LENGTH, "Invalid URL length");

        // Validate submitter
        require(submitter != address(0), "Submitter address cannot be zero");

        // Create a new URL data struct
        UrlData memory newUrl = UrlData({
            submitter: submitter,
            url: url
        });

        // Append to the array
        urls.push(newUrl);

        // Log the submission
        emit UrlSubmitted(submitter, url);
    }

    /// Get a URL by index
    /// @param index The index of the URL to retrieve
    /// @return submitter The address of the submitter
    /// @return url The URL submitted
    function getUrl(uint256 index) public view returns (address submitter, bytes memory url) {
        // Validate index
        require(index < urls.length, "Index out of bounds");

        // Return the stored URL and submitter
        UrlData storage data = urls[index];
        return (data.submitter, data.url);
    }

    /// Get total URL count
    /// @return The total number of URLs submitted
    function getTotalUrls() public view returns (uint256) {
        return urls.length;
    }
}

in my node server.js I have something like this
// Endpoint to send the transaction (proper Solana transaction handling)
app.post("/send-transaction", async (req, res) => {
    const { url } = req.body;
  
    // Ensure the URL is provided
    if (!url || url.length === 0) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "URL cannot be empty" });
    }
  
    try {
      const connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection("http://localhost:8899");
  
      // Your program ID (replace with the actual programId you're using)
      const programId = "...";
      const programPublicKey = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey(programId);
  
      // Encode URL as bytes using Buffer
      const encodedUrl = Buffer.from(url, 'utf-8');
  
      // Ensure you're sending both sender's public key and the URL as a concatenated Buffer
      const senderPublicKey = wallet.publicKey;
  
      // Concatenate public key and URL byte data
      const data = Buffer.concat([senderPublicKey.toBuffer(), encodedUrl]);
  
      // Log the prepared transaction for debugging
      console.log("Prepared transaction with URL (byte-encoded):", Array.from(data));
  
      // Create the transaction instruction with the concatenated data
      const transactionInstruction = new solanaWeb3.TransactionInstruction({
        keys: [
          { pubkey: wallet.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true } // Sender account
        ],
        programId: programPublicKey,
        data: data,  // Send both the sender public key and URL as raw bytes
      });
  
      // Create the transaction and add the instruction
      const transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction().add(transactionInstruction);
  
      // Send the transaction and confirm it
      const signature = await solanaWeb3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [wallet]);
  
      // Fetch logs after transaction
      const transactionStatus = await connection.getTransaction(signature);
  
      if (transactionStatus && transactionStatus.meta) {
        console.log("Transaction logs:", transactionStatus.meta.logMessages);
      } else {
        console.log("No logs found for the transaction.");
      }
  
      // Respond with transaction info
      res.json({ message: "Transaction sent", signature, logs: transactionStatus.meta.logMessages });
  
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error sending transaction:", err);
  
      if (err instanceof solanaWeb3.SendTransactionError) {
        console.log("Transaction failed with error:", err.message);
  
        // Get logs for failed transaction
        if (err.transactionSignature) {
          const connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection("http://localhost:8899");
          const logs = await connection.getTransactionLogs(err.transactionSignature);
          console.log("Transaction logs:", logs);
        }
      }
  
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to send transaction", details: err.message });
    }
  });

However, when I submit a transaction using my wallet private key, I get something like this:
Prepared transaction with URL (byte-encoded): [
  115,   2,  19, 129,  38, 170,  31,  23,  97,
  210, 117,  14,  52,  81,  30, 114,  68, 154,
  134, 191, 154, 107,   5,  95, 122, 100,  84,
   11, 112, 158,  63, 233, 103, 111, 111, 103,
  108, 101,  46,  99, 111, 109
]
Error sending transaction: SendTransactionError: Simulation failed.
Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid program argument.
Logs:
[
  "Program E9Bf214NakpVR45STzYBGCwABG4EVF8LhAvrcZhBQvJQ invoke [1]",
  "Program E9Bf214NakpVR45STzYBGCwABG4EVF8LhAvrcZhBQvJQ consumed 133 of 200000 compute units",
  "Program E9Bf214NakpVR45STzYBGCwABG4EVF8LhAvrcZhBQvJQ failed: invalid program argument"
].
Catch the `SendTransactionError` and call `getLogs()` on it for full details.
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/Users/.../node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:8216:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/Users/.../node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:8181:20)
    at async Connection.sendTransaction (/Users/.../node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:8172:12)
    at async Object.sendAndConfirmTransaction (/Users/.../node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:2273:21)
    at async /Users/.../server.js:119:25 {
  signature: '',
  transactionMessage: 'Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid program argument',
  transactionLogs: [
    'Program E9Bf214NakpVR45STzYBGCwABG4EVF8LhAvrcZhBQvJQ invoke [1]',
    'Program E9Bf214NakpVR45STzYBGCwABG4EVF8LhAvrcZhBQvJQ consumed 133 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program E9Bf214NakpVR45STzYBGCwABG4EVF8LhAvrcZhBQvJQ failed: invalid program argument'
  ]
}
Transaction failed with error: Simulation failed.
Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid program argument.
Logs:
[
  "Program E9Bf214NakpVR45STzYBGCwABG4EVF8LhAvrcZhBQvJQ invoke [1]",
  "Program E9Bf214NakpVR45STzYBGCwABG4EVF8LhAvrcZhBQvJQ consumed 133 of 200000 compute units",
  "Program E9Bf214NakpVR45STzYBGCwABG4EVF8LhAvrcZhBQvJQ failed: invalid program argument"
].
Catch the `SendTransactionError` and call `getLogs()` on it for full details.

I don't really understand how to send data to the contract.  I am coming from ERC-20 / Ethereum land and I had a single contract that could accept data and send tokens.  I want to do the same with SOLANG.  Is what I am gunning to do impossible?  Do I need to use anchor?  It's nontrivial to set up the environment to get code to compile, so I thought going straight to SOLANG would be faster and easier.
Please help.
